# Rcpp integration when C++ functions call each other

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am getting started with the Rcpp framwork for intergrating C++ function with R.

The following integration works just fine:

```
   cppFunction('
   double normal_dens( double x ) 
   {
     const double  SQRT2PI = 2.50662827463;
     return( exp(-x*x/2.0)/SQRT2PI );
   }
  ')
```

next I want to integrate:

```
   cppFunction('
   double test( double x ,double a) 
   {
    return( a* normal_dens(x);); 
   }
  ')
```

the internal cpp-compiler complains ( rightly-so ) that the function normal_dens is not known. What is the easiest way to do this?

many thx

Comment: i) This was asked on this very site just this week.  ii) This is a standard C/C++ question and covered in every decent book.  Look for 'function declaration' and 'header file', for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of these `cppFunction` calls create an independent shared library. They don't know about each other.

An easy alternative is to have all on the same file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double normal_dens( double x ) {
  const double  SQRT2PI = 2.50662827463;
  return( exp(-x*x/2.0)/SQRT2PI );
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test( double x ,double a){
  return( a* normal_dens(x);); 
}
```

and then call `sourceCpp` on this file. Then later, you'll want to learn how to make packages.